# HTML5 video with preview

Tags: javascript, html, youtube

I'm creating a website for a final work that I have to present at the end of the school.

and on my website I will have videos and I had the idea to do something like youtube. have the video and when I pass the mouse over the video image it would show a 3 second demo of the video. the problem is that for 3 days I've been searching for the code to be able to do this and still haven't found anything. could someone help me ???

Comment: What have your tried to do coding-wise? Are there any code examples you have written or snippets you can post?

Comment: all the sites I visited. had the demo and none of them was what I was looking for on my website I have the basic code for the video.

Comment: <video width="400" controls>
  <source src="video/steve.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

Comment: This question seems a tad broad. It'd be much easier to see an attempt at implementing this feature, because then we could explain why it isn't working and what you need to do to correct it. I don't know what the HTML for your thumbnails looks like, and there's definitely many many ways this could be accomplished.

Comment: Kindly share the code which you have written.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK the HTLM5 video player does not support a preview of a clip out of the box.

Your best bet would be able to use a third party video player or write a custom one. You may be able do something in JavaScript by using `onMouseover` to trigger a method which plays a 3 second clip.

As you mentioned YouTube, you may want to look at using the iframe which you can grab on videos near the comments, that may have what your after.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Well i can do this just please make me the answer i need repudiation

```js
function hover (){
window.setInterval(function(){
 $("video").get(0).play();
$("video").prop('muted', true); //mute
 var myVideo = document.getElementById("video")    
myVideo.controls = false;


 setTimeout(function(){
 myVideo.src = myVideo.src
 $("video").prop('muted', false);
 }, 2000);
}, 2000);

}

function sree(){
  hover();
  window.sree = _=>{};
}
```

```css
.vid{
background-color:black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span onmouseout="sree();">
<video src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4"  id="video" class ='vid'>

</video>
</span>
```

now buggy right and can only play once huh and no replay beter idea start in on hover huh like so

```js
document.getElementById("video").addEventListener("mouseover",function(){
 playvid();
 });
 function playvid(){
 $("video").get(0).play();
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video id='video'>
 <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  </video>
```

but if you want preview so bad probly best to just do a thumbnail